# jQuery / AJAX success function if statement not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, if-statement

I have a section of code I am using to check if the desired username is available using a jQuery AJAX call:

```
function check_username()
{

    // Set user_name to the current value of input #new_user_name
    var user_name = document.getElementById('new_user_name').value;

    // Ajax to check availability of username
    $.ajax({
        url: '_check_username.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 'user_name': user_name },
        success: function(data) {   

            var does_it_pass_or_fail = data;

            if ( does_it_pass_or_fail === "fail" )
            {
                alert( "Sorry, the username already exists. does_it_pass_or_fail = " + does_it_pass_or_fail ); );
            }
            else
            {
                alert( "That username is available! does_it_pass_or_fail = " + does_it_pass_or_fail ); );
            }
        }, error: function() {
           // Not sure what to put here...
        }
    });

}
```

The script works as expected -- I check the MySQL database on _check_username.php, and I successfully return a "pass" if the name's available, or "fail" if the name is already taken, and store it in the JS variable does_it_pass_or_fail.

However, regardless of whether does_it_pass_or_fail contains "pass" or "fail", I ONLY get the response "That username is available!"

So, the AJAX / PHP / MySQL portion seems to be working fine, but this simple JavaScript if statement has me stumped!

Comment: can you log the value of `does_it_pass_or_fail` to the console and show us?

Comment: You have a misplaced ");" on your alert statements. If you're not copying directing from the source I imagine it's some syntax mistake.

Comment: @twinlakes Interestingly enough, does_it_pass_or_fail in the console: 

ReferenceError: does_it_pass_or_fail is not defined

Comment: are you sure your server is sending a non-empty response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use firebug to debug the ajax request.
place

```
console.log(data);
```

in the success function.

Answer (score 1):

try using this:you had some syntax error in your code close to alert.try logging error also.

```
function check_username()
{

    // Set user_name to the current value of input #new_user_name
    var user_name = document.getElementById('new_user_name').value;

    // Ajax to check availability of username
    $.ajax({
        url: '_check_username.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 'user_name': user_name },
        success: function(data) {   

            var does_it_pass_or_fail = data;
            console.log(data);
            if ( does_it_pass_or_fail === "fail" )
            {
                alert( "Sorry, the username already exists. does_it_pass_or_fail = " + does_it_pass_or_fail );
            }
            else
            {
                alert( "That username is available! does_it_pass_or_fail = " + does_it_pass_or_fail );
            }
        }, error: function(erro) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

This may help you in debugging your ajax issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for leading me in the direction of further inspecting the AJAX call.

As it turns out, my '_check_username.php' script was returning a newline before returning "pass" or "fail" -- so, naturally, "\npass" is a different string than "pass". Once I realized this I was able to repair the script.